# Audio jQuery and currentTime on Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, audio

I am trying to get the currentTime of an HTML audio tag.
The following code works in Firefox but not in Google Chrome.
What is wrong with my code?

```
var audio = $('#audio'),
    totalTime = audio.attr('data-duration'),
    startTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalTime);
audio[0].currentTime = startTime; // No Chrome support at this point
```

Comment: HTML5 specs are not fully agreed upon between browsers, and this is another example of it. data-duration is not an officially spec'd attribute for the <audio> tag, thus not all browsers will support it. You'll probably need to write some JS to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) 2 instead. The doc is a bit tricky but Everything works fine now.